# Chrome Console Command Looping

Tags: jquery, loops

I'd like to loop a piece of jQuery code that clicks on an element for use in the google chrome console, but since I am not familiar with it, I do not know how to, any help would be greatly appreciated

The element is:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-more" data-action="more-feed">
```

Any help on what code to use to repeatedly click that element, and how to loop it for around about 5 minutes (if possible) would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery.trigger`. http://api.jquery.com/trigger/
You can simulate a click event by doing something like

```
for(var i = 0; i < /* number of times to loop */ 5; ++i)
    $(".btn").trigger("click");
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/d4Nfu/embedded/result/